# Predicting zoomlevel before this.map.fitBounds

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I am using mapbox in our application. Doing this.map.fitBounds(bound value) will zoomout or zoomin map to bound specified value. I need to find out zoom level (i.e map rendering after fit bounds)  before calling this.map.fitBounds. Is there any methods available in mapbox?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `L.Map`'s `getBoundsZoom` method:

> Returns the maximum zoom level on which the given bounds fit to the map view in its entirety. If inside (optional) is set to true, the method instead returns the minimum zoom level on which the map view fits into the given bounds in its entirety.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-getboundszoom